# Raid 6 or Raid 10 or Both + Hypervisor / VM's + Storage Config

Tags: virtualization, raid, virtual-machines, storage, hypervisor

I guess this is a multiple answer question, but looking on the web didn't find this kind of mind set.

I have a server (HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9) with 6 x 1,2 Tb SAS 10k (have 2 spares disks), and a storage with 24 x 1,2 Tb SAS 10k (have 2 spares disks), connected by 2 x 8 Gb/s fiber link, will run a hypervisor (we don't have a SD Card for the hypervisor alone and not decided with one to go, as it has to be free - ESXi + open source manager or oVirt or other KVM solution - any advice on here?) and run something like 10 to 15 VMs (probably will run CentOS on all of them if not user specified) - for what will be running:

- Various web applications with database writing - text and numbers but not massive amount of data per user - (home made, but can peak 1000 users simultaneously and will grow)
- Telnet / SSH > Telecom network collect scripts (some being massive text collectors / filters with processing)
- Databases processing for automatically generated reports (texts inner / left / right join's)

For the storage, what will go in (for now):

- Logs and databases of the web applications and reports management
- Big Data + BI home made solution on the future
- Backup?

For the Server, I was thinking on going full Raid 10 (6x 1,2 Tb) for performance and faster recover if anything goes wrong (**didn't drop the raid 1 possibility too**), didn't thought about the partitions / partitions type yet, any performance related advice on Raid and Partition Setup for performance and reliably?

For the storage I actually don't know which way to go, as the possibilites are bigger, maybe big raid 6 or 10? or split on 3 x raid 6? We didn't looked for backups strategy yet too, but a possibility was letting a raid or disks alone for backup, while we don't a solutions or others servers to backup to.

For now I have to work with that, can't consider buying anything else.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide specific details on the make and model of the storage attached to the server?

Comment: It is a HPE MSA 2040 SAN Storage with 24x 1,2 Tb 10k SAS, and two fibre channel controllers.

Comment: R6 won't work for that many disks, R60 will and will be very safe but have you not considered just using R10?

Comment: Yeah I found out that R6 would suck. But comparing R60 vs R10, is just a matter of reliability (and a little more capacity) vs performance, right? It is difficult to say because the application guys doesn't know what kind of IO they will need.  I ended up going on raid 10 for the server, installed CentOS + KVM and now just playing with Virt Manager and oVirt to see which one will use.